# call a function every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a simple Android app and I need a function to be called every 5 seconds. I can't flipping figure it out. 
The function I need to call every 5 seconds is otherFunction()

```
   Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();

   Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        otherFunction();        
        mSystemUiHider.hide();


    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to the following example:

```
Handler locationPrompt = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(msg.what==SUBJECT){
            onLocationChanged(location);
            sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SUBJECT, REFRESH);
        }
    }

};
```

when calling this method:

```
locationPrompt.sendEmptyMessage(SUBJECT);
```

where

```
final static long REFRESH = 10 * 1000;
final static int SUBJECT = 0;
```

So this method gets called every 10 seconds here.\

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, specifically the schedule methods.

Comment: should try and provide an example.